# How to get DISTINCT row based on a column from UNION

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I have a table based on `UNION` of 2 different tables:

```
ResultTable = 
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            'Table1',
            "Name", 'Table1'[name] ,
            "Number", 'Table1'[number]
        ) ,
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            'Table2',
            "Name", 'Table2'[name] ,
            "Number", 'Table2'[number]
        )
    )
```

Here is the `ResultTable` output:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 5 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |

Can I get distinct rows based on the `Number` column so that it becomes:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| C | 5 |
| B | 4 |

Comment: Please add `Name = A, Number = 4` to your `ResultTable` and adjust your desired outcome based on this. Right now it is a bit unclear whether you want distinct rows (solved by @Andrey), or one row per `Number` value, at which point it becomes necessary to somehow isolate the `Name` value that goes to each distinct `Number` - hinted to by @Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output still describes a simple distinct on the entire `UNION` result, so just wrap it in `DISTINCT`:

```
ResultTable = 
    DISTINCT (
        UNION (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                'Table1',
                "Name", 'Table1'[name] ,
                "Number", 'Table1'[number]
            ) ,
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                'Table2',
                "Name", 'Table2'[name] ,
                "Number", 'Table2'[number]
            )
        )
    )
```

Did you mean to do a group by NUMBER, while implementing some logic for picking the right NAME out of aggregation?

Comment: This is the way. Simple and does exactly what is required.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have to specify an **aggregation** in case there are different names for a single number. This is not the case with your sample data, so either **MIN()** or **MAX()** will work. Use this expression as a **calculated table**:

```
Distinct Numbers = 
SUMMARIZE(
    ResultTable,
    ResultTable[Number],
    "Name", MIN(ResultTable[Name])
)
```

[image]